# MongoDB shell Update within forEach

Tags: mongodb, collections, foreach, cursor

I am trying to update a specific menu with a list of items. The cursor has this list and I have tested that to make sure. I am trying to loop through each item in the cursor and push that item's id into the menu's item list. The below code completes with no errors but does not actually alter the items field of the menu. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
cursor.forEach(function(item){
    db.menus.update(
        {_id: 5806639da77d6e0f00ac902c}, 
        {$push: {"items": item._id}}, 
        {upsert: true}
    );  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are updating the element passing `5806639da77d6e0f00ac902c` but notice this is not a valid parameter, as it's not a string and it's not an ObjectId.

If on your database you have the _ids as objectIds, try converting it first:

```
db.menus.update(
    {_id: ObjectId("5806639da77d6e0f00ac902c")}, 
    {$push: {"items": item._id}}, 
    {upsert: true}
);
```